# NInject 1.5 Documentation

Tags: ninject

I have a project that targets .Net Framework 3.0 - and I don't want at this stage to target it at 3.5. I do however want to use NInject in it so I'm limited to NInject 1.5 - but I'm struggling to find any documentation on how to use NInject 1.5.

I've managed to find the NInject1 wiki [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject1/wiki) but something still seems to be missing in the explanation (i.e. I can't find any Bind method as described in the Wiki).

Please anyone that could point me in the direction of some more complete documentation would be great ... if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.co.nz/2009/08/first-steps-into-dependency-injection.html) has helped no end...

I was failing to inherit from StandardModule. The original wiki didn't seem to mention this, certainly not where I was looking.